# Account List by Rep Matrix Report

Tags: reporting, list, matrix

How can I create a report in SFDC where I can see the target accounts assigned by reps at a glance (in a matrix format), like this:

[image: Matrix Account List by Sales Rep]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take some time to review [ask] and take the [tour]. If you are new to salesforce, I can recommend you get started with Trailhead modules at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/reports_dashboards and update your post with a specific problem you are encountering while attempting to create a report. this will at least show that you have put a minimum level of effort prior to asking how to questions on the forum. As is, we have no way of knowing what you have tried and not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Matrix reports are generally used for comparing related totals and groups and summarize data by both rows and columns. Unfortunately, you cannot create a matrix report to show this information. The beast way to go would be to create a summary report.